# Haskell case branch with multiple expressions

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I use pattern match to handle multiple cases like this:

```
case maybeV of Nothing -> doWhenNothing 
               Just something -> doWhenSomethingExpression_1
                                 doWhenSomethingExpression_2
```

it seems compiler considers the second expression `doWhenSomethingExpression_2` as argument to `doWhenSomethingExpression_1` and reports error. How to handle this case when I have multiple expressions in one branch of `case` ?

BTW, I think I can use `if` to judge the `maybe` value, but is using `if` a good way?

Comment: Is this a Monad (`do` environment)? Haskell is a functional language, so you can't simply enumerate instructions...

Comment: You should add the type of `doWhenSomething...` and other related information in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your code is in a monad, you probably want something like this:

```
case maybeV of Nothing -> doWhenNothing 
               Just something -> do
                 doWhenSomethingExpression_1
                 doWhenSomethingExpression_2
```